# Why is there no constant for the intent to launch the emergency dialler?

Tags: android, android-intent

The emergency dialer can be launched with an intent with the action "com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL" However, there is no constant in the Intents class for this. Why is that?
I'd rather not use something that can be easily broken in a later version of Android.

How can the emergency dialer be launched reliably? I don't want to actually call any number directly, just open the dialer.

Comment: what are you asking here? you think that the intent framework/system will change or how the dialer is used or implemented will change?

Comment: Can you use the following public static? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/idea133/src/com/android/phone/EmergencyDialer.java#72

Answer (score 4):

You can launch the Emergency Dialer as follow (still hard-coded):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.phone/.EmergencyDialer"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I realise this, it's just that without an api entry to it, google can break it anytime. That's why I wanted an API constant in particular.